# only the last canvas object in an array will update

Tags: javascript, canvas

I dont know exactly *what* the problem *is*, so creating a minimal reproducable example may be difficult, but I will try to exclude code that is not relevent to the problem.
I have tried debugging it on my own and looking around the internet.
so, I have a function that creates a new 'turret' object and puts it in an array. the new one updates but all the other ones exept the new one do not. i have verifyed they still exist. I have two things I think may be the problem;

1. i have two scripts
   my loop is not working correctly
   everything looks fine and i dont know what i should be looking for to fix it.
   for simplicity assume things that have not been defined ARE defined. I can provide code as-needed
   also as I am butchering my code to turn it into a reproducable example there may be some inconsistancys.

```
//i dont think this is the problem
var gameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.canvas.id = "canvas";
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            gameArea.x = e.pageX;
            gameArea.y = e.pageY;
            
        })
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            gameArea.keys = (gameArea.keys || []);
            gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (r) {
            gameArea.x2 = r.pageX;
            gameArea.y2 = r.pageY;
        })
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (r) {
            gameArea.x2 = false;
            gameArea.y2 = false;
        })
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}
//update the game
function updateGameArea() {
    //clear screen
    var basicTowerr = getTower(0);
    gameArea.clear();
    //set cursor selection snapping to grid
    gridSnap(30);
    if(gameArea.x2 && gameArea.y2) {
        buildTower(xGridIndex,yGridIndex, basicTowerr);
    }
    updateTowers();
}
//this is my second script
var towers = [];
var towerType = [];





//creates new 'tower' object
function tower(size, dmg, fr, hp) {
   this.size = size*30;
this.dmg = dmg;
this.fr = fr;
this.hp = hp;
   this.setPos = function(x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    this.updatet = function() {
    
            
            
   
      var ctx = gameArea.context;
       ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(0);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(this.size / -2, this.size / -2, this.size, this.size);
        ctx.restore();    
    }
    }

    function updateTowers() {
for(var m = 0;m < towers.length; m++) {
    towers[m].updatet();
   
}
}
var basicTower = new tower(1, 5, 1, 1);

towerType[0] = basicTower;
function getTower(index) {
    return towerType[index];
}
function buildTower(x,y, type) {
  //  document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = basicTower;
 // if(blockAt[xGridIndex][yGridIndex] == 0) {
    towers.push(type);
    
    towers[towers.length - 1].setPos(selecX,selecY);
    blockAt[xGridIndex][yGridIndex] = towers[towers.length - 1];
    towers[towers.length - 1].updatet();
//}
}

//this differnt  script
function gridSnap(boxSize) {
    var selecGridX = gameArea.x / boxSize;
    var selecGridY = gameArea.y / boxSize;
     xGridIndex = Math.round(selecGridX);
     yGridIndex = Math.round(selecGridY);
    selecX = Math.round(selecGridX) * boxSize - boxSize/2;
    selecY = Math.round(selecGridY)  * boxSize - boxSize/2;
    selec.x = selecX;
    selec.y = selecY;
     selecxX = selecX;
     selecxY = selecY;
}
```

i tried updateing them from the main script useing a function but it only updates the last one in the array

Comment: `towers.push(type);` means `towers.push(basicTower);`, right? You’re repeating the exact same identical object over and over. The `towers` array only ever contains a single distinct object.